# PHP create object inside it's own constructor

Tags: php, object, constructor, get

EDIT: Link to my first question. Might clear some things up.
[PHP Get corresponding data, with default and error handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722294/php-get-corresponding-data-with-default-and-error-handling)

I have a function that checks if a GET statement exists. If so, it passes the value to a other function that then selects a class based on the value of the GET statement.

explaining:
The url = Page=Contact
The GetFormVariable approves it, and the class Contact is selected and it will give back a string. This string is used as an object 'Content' that, as it says, creats the content of the page.

```
public function getFormVariable($value){

    switch (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
        case 'GET':
            if (isset($_GET[$value]) && $_GET[$value] != NULL) {
                return $_GET[$value];
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
            break;
            case 'POST':
                if (isset($POST[$value]) && $POST[$value] != NULL) {
                return $POST[$value];
            }
            else{
                    return false;
            }
                break;

        default:
            return false;

    }
}
```

Now the question.
When there is no GET statement in the url. The GetFormVariable returns false. And this means there is nothing shown.

How do i give this constructor.

```
public function SetProperty ($prob, $val){
    $this->$prob = $val;
}
```

The information to create the ContentHome.
SetProperty('Content', 'ContentHome');

Sorry for poor explanation, if anything is unclear please tell me so.

Comment: By using default values?

Comment: @gontrollez I am not sure what you mean?

Comment: There's a section [on this page of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) entitled `Default argument values`

Comment: I do get your question, mostly because I've read your two previous questions today. Maybe you should have provided a link to the last one. One thing you may not know : a POST request may have GET vars as well as POST vars (whereas a GET request can only have GET vars).

Comment: @Calimero You again :) Thank you for helping me, but you have done too much. I really appreciate that you keep helping me. But i can't keep knocking on your door for help.

Comment: You're most welcome. Let me add that managing input parameters is a universal need in most php applications, it has been implemented time and again in a number of php frameworks, classes, and applications. You may benefit a lot from browsing what already exists out there that fit your needs, instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting we close this question as unclear what you're asking, but decided to throw some help on the provided code sample anyway...

You can strip this down dramatically, and since there's no context, the function can be `static` too.

```
static public function getFormVariable($value)
{
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' &&
       isset($_GET[$value])                &&
       !empty($_GET[$value]))
        return $_GET[$value];

    elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' &&
           isset($POST[$value])                 &&
           !empty($POST[$value]))
        return $POST[$value];

    return false;
}
```

Your original `isset` and `!= NULL` checks were doing the same check. Maybe you want the `empty()` check as a third check, but [look it up](http://php.net/empty) to be certain.

Comment: When the getFormVariable() returns false, as in there is no actual GET statement in the url, It has to load a class. These classes are loaded/activated through a other file in an object. Here is the object $ConfigPage->SetProperty('Content', 'ContentHome'); and then in the file where the getFormVariable() function the object gets constructed and used. Now how do i construct this Content in the constructor itself?

Comment: All `getFormVariable` does is look for values in `$_GET` or `$_POST`. Instantiating a class based on this information for some values should be handled *outside* of `getFormVariable`.

Comment: Although your code was not the solution, you did improve my own code. So hearby i flag your response as the solution since i am giving up this question. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear.

How you call getFormVariable? How you use SetProperty with the information getFormVariable provides?

As far as I understood, you mean this...

```
$var = getFormVariable(???);

if (false === $var)
{
    SetProperty('Content', 'ContentHome');
} else {
    SetProperty('var', $var);
}
```